# sql data conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There is something wrong with a value I am asking the database to find

```
string locationCode = Server.UrlDecode(Request["locationCode"].ToString().Trim());
string ID = Server.UrlDecode(Request["id"].ToString().Trim());

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAccounts"]);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand getEstC = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(EstablishmentCode) FROM Establishments WHERE EstablishmentCode = " + locationCode + " AND ID <> " + ID, myConnection);
            estCount = (Int32)getEstC.ExecuteScalar();
```

I think there is something wrong with the value of ID being a string, but in the database it's an int. I thought sql would take care of the conversion but apparently not. The main error message is:

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'PRU1' to data type int."

The line number identified in the message was the last line of code I posted above.

Comment: What are the values of `locationCode` and `ID` when you get the error? What are the datatypes of the `EstablishmentCode` and `ID` columns? It is *trying* to 'take care of the conversion', but obviously something is not of an appropriate type.

Comment: Also, creating SQL statements like this is a horrible, horrible idea. Please do yourself a favor and do some research on parameterized queries.

Answer (score 3):

Try using parameterized query, not only it helps with preventing SQL injection, it also helps with quotes and escaping characters.

In your case:

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed
>   when converting the nvarchar value 'PRU1' to data type int."

You get the errror because you omit the quotes and SQL server treats it as an INT, thus fail to convert `PRU1` to a int.

You should never build your query like this, instead you want to prepare the statement.

```
string locationCode = Server.UrlDecode(Request["locationCode"].ToString().Trim());
string ID = Server.UrlDecode(Request["id"].ToString().Trim());

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAccounts"]))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    @"SELECT COUNT(EstablishmentCode) 
      FROM Establishments 
      WHERE EstablishmentCode = @locationCode  AND ID <> @ID",
    con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locationCode", locationCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    }
}
```

---

It is recommended to be explicit with type conversion:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@locationCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = locationCode;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must compare data of same data type. If your ID column is of type Int then you must pass in Int and not a string as it will treat it as a varchar

Comment: Saying you may only compare data of the same type is a bit misleading. Most (all?) SQL engines are fully capable of attempting to convert one datatype to another for comparison. See, for example: `SELECT CASE WHEN 1='1' THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you pass a string that cannot be converted to int at some point. to make sure, try to add something like that:

```
int intId = int.Parse(ID);
```

This should throw an exception if your string cannot be converted to int.